# Error: connect ETIMEDOUT ,Node js how to communicate between localhost API's

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have some back-end services which are listening on port 8080. And I have another API in node js which is listening on port 3000 on localhost.

How can I communicate from node server to the back-end API's?

This is my node js code:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('got validate request');

  var options =  {
    host:'localhost',
    port:8080,
    path:'/***/getservice',
    method:'GET'
  }

  http.request(options, function (response) {
    console.log('response:', response); // Print the error if one occurred
    res.json(response);
    res.end();
  });
});
```

The above code causes Error: connect ETIMEDOUT.